# How to loop a json keys result from bash script

Tags: json, bash, jq

input.json:-

```
{
"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "user": {
    "address": "USA",
    "email": "user@gmail.com"
  }
}
}
```

Command:-

```
result=$(cat input.json | jq -r '.menu | keys[]')
```

Result:-

```
id
value
user
```

Loop through result:-

```
for type in "${result[@]}"
do
    echo "--$type--"
done
```

Output:-

```
--id
value
user--
```

I want to do process the keys values in a loop. When I do the above, It result as a single string.

How can I do a loop with json keys result in bash script?

Comment: using `bash` is redundant in such case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *canonical* way :

```
file='input.json'
cat "$file" | jq -r '.menu | keys[]' | 
while IFS= read -r value; do
    echo "$value"
done
```

[bash faq #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

---

But you seems to want an array, so the syntax is (missing parentheses) :

```
file='input.json'

result=( $(cat "$file" | jq -r '.menu | keys[]') )

for type in "${result[@]}"; do
    echo "--$type--"
done
```

### Output:

```
--id--
--value--
--user--
```

Comment: I am getting jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: when executing second approach.

Comment: Still I get error in this line result=( $(jq -r '.menu | keys[]' input.json) ) after your updation. Also I want input.json name to be dynamic

Comment: result=( $(cat input.json | jq -r '.menu | keys[]') ). this works.

Comment: You need to install it (no deps)

Comment: Thanks, the only solution actually working for my case !

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` to just print an object keys from JSON data is redundant.
**`Jq`** is able to handle it by itself. Use the following simple **`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.menu | keys_unsorted[] | "--"+ . +"--"' input.json
```

The output:

```
--id--
--value--
--user--
```